# Iterate through subfolders and collect paths of files starting with a defined string

Tags: php

I am building a site which has a "gallery" folder with images. Inside the "gallery" folder there are other sub-folders, one for each image category. For example:

```
gallery
   |---foo
   |---bar
   |---cat
```

Inside these folders there are some images among the others that their name starts with "slideshow_".

I want to write a script that searches all folders inside "gallery" and assign their path in an array variable. The names and the number of sub-folders should be considered unknown.

I know how to do it by hardcoding names and merging the results from `glob('gallery/{name}/slideshow_*')` but I want something better, preferrably with SPL. I have tried this with no success:

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('assets/img/gallery');

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $filename => $file) {
      $slideshow_images[] = glob('slideshow_*');      
}
```

Comment: since your glob() call doesn't include the filename/path that the iterator is providing, it's just going to be globbing in your script's current working directory, and return the SAME set of filenames each time. You probably want [ReturnsiveRegexIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveregexiterator.construct.php) instead, so you can do filename matching directly in the iterator.

Comment: Can you make it an answer plz because I 've never used it again and to accept it?

Answer (score 4):

If you could use Symfony Finder, this is a breeze:

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in('assets/img/gallery')->name('slideshow_*');
foreach ($finder as $file) {
    // Do magic here
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html

Comment: Thanks, it is nice but I want to use vanilla PHP.